# if else statement not working properly within viewholder and for loop in android

Tags: android, sqlite, for-loop, if-statement, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set a text view in my recycler adapter and this text is receiving from database when i use code inside for loop and check condition using if else statement but this statement is not working properly. can anyone help me please.

here is my code

```
pu

blic class Quran16linesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Quran16linesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        List<QuranModel> list;
        List<PageSearchmodel> pageSearchmodels;
        int page;
    
        private static int surah_number = 0;
    
    
        private int sura = 1;
        Context context;
    
        public Quran16linesAdapter(Context context, List<QuranModel> list, List<PageSearchmodel> searchmodelList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
            this.pageSearchmodels = searchmodelList;
    
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Quran16linesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_16lines, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Quran16linesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            PageSearchmodel pageSearchmodel = pageSearchmodels.get(position);
    
            page = pageSearchmodel.getPage();
    
            Quran_db quranDb = new Quran_db(context);
    
            List<QuranModel> pagesList = quranDb.readPage(page);
    
    
            SpannableStringBuilder temp_spannableRemaingg = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
            for (int i = 0; i < pagesList.size(); i++) {
                QuranModel quranModel = pagesList.get(i);
                 final int aya_in_surah =quranModel.getAya_number_in_surah();
     Log.d("Ayah Number", "onBindViewHolder: "+aya_in_surah);
                if ( aya_in_surah ==1) {
                    holder.surah_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.surah_name.setText("بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ");
    
                }
                temp_spannableRemaingg.append(quranModel.getArabic());
    
    
            }
            holder.tv_per16lines.setText(temp_spannableRemaingg);
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private final TextView tv_per16lines;
            private final TextView surah_name;
    
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                surah_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.surah_name);
                tv_per16lines = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_per16Line);
    
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Here is My log cat Values but after 5-6 view if statement automatically went to true
and print the result ...

```
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 1
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 2
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 3
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 4
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 5
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 6
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 7
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 1
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 2
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 3
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 4
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 5
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 6
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 7
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 8
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 9
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 10
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 11
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 12
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 13
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 14
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 15
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 16
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 17
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 18
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 19
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 20
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 21
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 22
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 23
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 24
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 25
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 26
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 27
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 28
D/Ayah Number: onBindViewHolder: 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( aya_in_surah ==1) {
holder.surah_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.surah_name.setText("بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ");
}else{
holder.surah_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.surah_name.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Not working only else statement is executing

Comment: final int aya_in_surah =quranModel.getAya_number_in_surah();
change this to (remove final)
 int aya_in_surah =quranModel.getAya_number_in_surah();

Comment: not working again